# programmatically add appointment directly to calendar in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, calendar

How to programmatically add appointment directly to calendar without user intervention in windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1):

You can add appointment with the SaveAppointmentTask: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207038(v=vs.105).aspx

Please note that you can't silently create an appointment as the user interaction is needed for security reason.

Comment: Is there any solution to this problem because i want to add appointment silently in my application. Can you help me or instruct me please?